# How to keep the value of a variable(int) alive after a submit button click so as to use its value again in the same page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

This is the 1st part of the code, plz look at the variable $Tno.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $Tno=$_POST['Tno'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM docs WHERE Tno='$Tno'";

    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Data not selected');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $Tassign = $row["Tassign"];
    }     
}   



if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{    
    $ti="INSERT INTO approval(Tno, approval)values('$Tno','Approved')";
    $tj=mysql_query($ti) or ('Data Not Inserted');
    if($tj){
        echo "All set!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I need $Tno value in this part of the code also to insert in the DB. But its storing ZERO. Any solutions??

Comment: Are those 2 separate submission pages? If so, please specify.
Nvm I see. You need to let us know which page is which, otherwise people will think your logic is flawed, down vote you and not help you answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @zander. :)
Its a single page with two separate blocks of code.

Comment: Ohh I see.. So you keep resubmitting to that one page?

Comment: yeah actually there's a submit button which when pressed fetches the data from mysql. After viewing the fetched results the user approves the data by clicking another button.

Comment: Well show us your front end forms then. You could always just load in the data that needs to be approved, into a HTML Form, and when the user clicks submit, he/she posts it to your PHP script, and you can access it using `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the following ways

**1)Session**

You can store data in the session and than you can use it to insert the data in the database

```
 session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $Tno=$_POST['Tno'];
    $_SESSION['Tno'] = $Tno
        $query="SELECT * FROM docs WHERE Tno='$Tno'";

        $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Data not selected');

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $Tassign = $row["Tassign"];
        }     
    }   



    if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
    {    
$Tno = $_SESSION['Tno'];
        $ti="INSERT INTO approval(Tno, approval)values('$Tno','Approved')";
        $tj=mysql_query($ti) or ('Data Not Inserted');
        if($tj){
            echo "All set!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        }
    }
```

**2) By using GET Method**

You can also use $_GET method to get the value of Tno and than you can insert into your database

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{    
$Tno = $_GET['Tno'];
    $ti="INSERT INTO approval(Tno, approval)values('$Tno','Approved')";
    $tj=mysql_query($ti) or ('Data Not Inserted');
    if($tj){
        echo "All set!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually there's a submit button on my page which when pressed fetches the data from mysql. After viewing the fetched results(on the same page) the user approves the data by clicking another button on the same page. Now when this 2nd submit button is clicked, A text goes to database (i.e. "Approved") along with the variabe "$Tno". Now problem is that I am not able to sent $Tno to database because I think when the second submit button is clicked, variable $Tno becomes empty. Any solution to this?

Comment: $Tno will become empty because first condition if(isset($_POST['submit'])) is not executed and $Tno value is unset. If you want to keep it's value than use session for the purpose. It will store the data for you to continue with your script

Comment: exactly!! Now i tried using session as told by @Zander. but still its not working..plz help me.

Comment: Are you starting the session using session_start(). Its the common mistake.

Comment: I have simply added these two lines. $_SESSION['Tno'] = $Tno; and $Tno = $_SESSION['Tno']; on appropriate places as suggested by zander. Could you plz guide me how to do it properly i am quite new to php.

Comment: Please read my answer i have explained and wrote the code for you under session . Use my code and than tell me it works for you or not

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the statement

$query="SELECT * FROM docs WHERE Tno='$Tno'";

instead use
$query="SELECT * FROM docs";

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $Tassign=$row["Tassign"];

      *// Now perform the matching* 

     **If ($Tassign==$Tno)**
     {
     *// enter your functionality here
      }
      }
```

Now the values would be fetched from database and You can perform specific operation on the data fetched

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 ways you could go about it.
Either using GET, or Session. I don't know how you're directing over from Page 1 to 2. So I will just rather use Session to be safe.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $Tno=$_POST['Tno'];
    // Store the TNO value in the session
    $_SESSION['Tno'] = $Tno;
    $query="SELECT * FROM docs WHERE Tno='$Tno'";

    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Data not selected');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $Tassign = $row["Tassign"];
    }     
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{   
    // Now get the TNO value here
    $Tno = $_SESSION['Tno'];
    $ti="INSERT INTO approval(Tno, approval)values('$Tno;,'Approved')";
    $tj=mysql_query($ti) or ('Data Not Inserted');
    if($tj){
        echo "All set!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    }
}
```